# Store Objects of Different Type in Array and Call their Methods

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class Key<T> where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        private T[] _data;
        public int Count {get; set;}
        public IComparer<T> Comparer;
        // property for holding what order the keys can occupy
        public bool[] orders = {false,false,false}; // false until proven

        public Key(T[] data, IComparer<T> comparer)
        {
            this._data = data;
            this.Count = data.Length;
            this.Comparer = comparer;
        }

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                if (index >= Count || index < 0) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
                return _data[index];
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to store multiple objects from this class in a single array and then check the order of their values. However some of the objects I am initialising will be of int type and others of string type, additionally I would like to have extendibility for adding more types in the future, so how do I store the objects of different type in a single array and still be able to call their methods?

I tried using an array of objects but I still have to cast to the key without knowing the type I want to cast to.

Edit: Ok so some more detail. This is part of a problem task I have been given as part of a uni course I am doing - WAIT, LET ME FINISH! - I understand the general problem and have already solved it, the issue is that I dislike my solution because it can't be extended.

The Task: You are given three sets of data that together describe a set of objects. Example: a string set of names, an int set of ages, and an int set of weights. The combined values at index 0 describe object 0, the combined values at index 1 describe object 1, etc. The sets are sorted in a particular way such that one set is the primary key, another is the secondary key (breaks ties in the first set) and another is the final key (breaks ties in the second set). You are also given the comparer for each set. Determine which combinations of primary, secondary and final keys are possible.

So in my current solution I just make a bool array for each of the three sets to keep track of what key orders they can be. To determine if a set can be primary I just check if the set is fully sorted. To determine if a set can be secondary I make a dictionary of the values and indexes of all the tied values in the primary set, I then check if the values at those indexes in the secondary set are sorted. If yes, then it can be secondary. I just repeat with the final key. Finally, I convert all of the combinations into strings (example: "NWA" : Name primary, Weight secondary, and Age final) and return a list of all the combinations as strings - part of the requirements.

Now the problem with this solution is that I have to hard code the various combinations. This makes the solution less readable and less extendible. What I want to do is just make a class to hold the different sets, their comparers, string translation and possible key orders (which I've done with my Key class), then throw all the objects from this class into an array I can nicely iterate over to find all the combinations.

So far I can't do this because I have to specify the type in place of the generic when initialising an array. Is it even possible to do what I want in C# or is there some better way of doing this?

Also I don't want to be able to this just for this problem, but so I know how to do it in the future to make my life easier.

Comment: Your question is unclear because you do not known what type to cast to. I can only advise you to write down the benefits/disadvantages for every data-type, and then choose the best one

Comment: It sounds like you either want a completely different design that doesn't require you to do this, or perhaps discriminated unions (not natively supported in C# at this time). If you could tell us more about the problem you're trying to solve by doing this, and the type of data involved, we could probably recommend a better solution.

Comment: what do you mean by `check the order of their values` & `still have to cast to the key`? provide more details about the problem, along with what you have tried

Comment: I'd argue having a *single* array for completely different, unrelated things, is a bad idea. What has an integer in comon with a string? What can you do on both? Literally nothing, so there's no reason to handle them tigether in any way. Simply don't do that, as it makes your life only harder by implementing wrappers and unwrappers.

Comment: How do you intend to order `1` and `"1"`? Just convert everything to string and compare strings?

Comment: numbers should (at least) be prepended with some (but how many?) zero's.  You definitely do no want to sort `10` between `1` and `2`.

Comment: I wonder how one would sort `[1, "3", "MyString", DateTime.Now, new MyClass()]`

Comment: "I understand the general problem and have already solved it"   I think you are making an overcomplicated solution to a simple problem, so might I suggest to rethink your solution (and re-read the problem?)

Comment: "I want to store multiple objects from this class in a single array"  Can you add, an example, of the multiple objects?, and what you expect to be in that single array?